# Obtain data from my jsp table to my spring controller

Tags: java, javascript, spring, hibernate, jsp

can someone help me, im tryng to obtain data (View->Controller) from a table i redered in this way:

Controller level:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/table")
public ModelAndView renderTable() {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("/table"); 
    List<MyObjects> objects = getObjects();
    mv.add("configs",objects);
    return mv;
}
```

JSP:

```
<c:if test="${not empty configs}">
<table class="tablaListado" cellspacing="0">
    <c:forEach var="o" items="${configs}">
        <tr class="renglonListado">
            <td class="colListado">${o.key}</td>
            <td class="colListado"><input type="text" class="valor" value="${o.value}" onchange="marcarCambio(this.parentNode.parentNode);"></td>
            <td class="colListado"></td>   
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

As you see there is an input that the user can edit its value, and i want to obtain this value to update it in my DB.

Can someone help me?

Comment: What have you tried? Is your table contained within a form or are you doing it with javascript?

Comment: Currently, Its not inside a form, i would like to update the model and recieve it in another method after making a post, but im not sure how to update it

Answer (score 1):

You can do followings:

1. Create a controller method (HTTP POST) receiving data in the server side.
2. Put your view code inside a form and bind (via action) this form with your controller POST method.
3. Instead of step 2, you could use JavaScript to gather your input submit the data using AJAX.

Comment: I would like to do the second one but how or when is the model updated? (The model i already rendered).

Comment: In JSP server side data model is not tightly coupled with view. In that case you need to capture data of each row and need to submit in controller. I think it will be difficult to submit the whole table model into the controller. I will suggest to use Master-Detail pattern in that case.